# A property of oscillation function

Tags: real-analysis

I was solving an exercise from Stein-Shakarchi's Real Analysis, regarding the set of discontinuities of a Riemann integrable function $f$ on $[a,b]$.

Let $\mbox{osc}(f,c,r)=\sup \{ |f(x)-f(y)| :  x,y \mbox{ lie in open ball of radius $r$ around $c$ and in $[a,b]$} \}$

It is easy to see that if $r<r'$ then ${\rm osc}(f,c,r) \le {\rm osc}(f,c,r')$.

Define $\mbox{osc}(f,c)=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} {\rm osc}(f,c,r)$.

**Exercies:** For $\epsilon>0$, the set $A_{\epsilon}:= \{ c\in [a,b] : \mbox{osc}(f,c)\ge \epsilon \}$ is closed subset of $[a,b]$.

I tried to work it out but I didn't get what is key point for the closedness of $A_{\epsilon}$. Any hint?

This question may have been addressed here; but without looking solution, I tried myself, but didn't proceed.

Comment: Hint: Assume the set was open, then there would be a conververging series of discontinuity's$\geq\epsilon.$

Comment: This is ridiculous. If a set is not open you cannot conclude that it is closed. I wonder how this comment got an upvote.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, True I should have said "assume it is not closed" instead of open. (I am deeply ashamed of myself). But the person asking the question eventually figured out the answere so maybe the comment didn't do that much harm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Let $c_n$ be a sequence in $A_{\epsilon}$ with $c_n\rightarrow c$. We show $c\in A_{\epsilon}$.

(2) Suppose $c\notin A_{\epsilon}$. Then ${\rm osc}(f,c)< \epsilon$.

(3) $\Rightarrow$ ${\rm osc}(f,c,\frac{1}{k})<\epsilon$ for all sufficiently large $k$'s (say $k\ge k_0$).

(4) Consider $I:=(c-\frac{1}{k_0}, c+\frac{1}{k_0})$; so ${\rm osc}(f,I)<\epsilon$.

(5)  Choose $c_N$ so close to $c$ that $J:=(c_N-\delta, c_N+\delta)$ will lie in interval $I$ for some $\delta>0$.

(6) Since $J\subseteq I$, so ${\rm osc}(f,J)\le {\rm osc}(f,I) <\epsilon$. Hence ${\rm osc}(f,c_N)\le {\rm osc}(f,J)<\epsilon$; contradiction.